# Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr. }

Tags: tables

I get this error with my table. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}
    \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
        \begin{tabular}{lc|c}
            \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Barcelona Basic Model (BBM)\\ (Alonso et al., 1990)\end{tabular}} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Rockfill Model (RM)\\ (Compressibility part described in\\ Oldecop & Alonso, 2001)\end{tabular} \\ \hline
            \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Isotropic elastoplastic\\ volumetric\\ deformation\end{tabular}} & $d\epsilon_v=\frac{\lambda(s)}{(1+e)}\frac{dp}{p}$ & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$d\epsilon_v = \lambda^i dp ,p \leq p_y$ \\ $d\epsilon_v = \lambda^i dp + \lambda^d (s)dp ,p > p_y$\end{tabular} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multirow{3}{*}{} & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$\lambda_i+\lambda^d(s)$ \\ $\lambda^d (s) = \lambda_0^d - \alpha_{s} ln \left ( \frac{s+p_{atm}}{p_{atm}} \right )$\end{tabular}} \\
            \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Volumetric\\ compressibility index\end{tabular} &  &  \\
            \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} &  &  \\
            \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Hardening law} &  & $dp_0^* = \frac{d\epsilon_v^p}{\lambda_i -\kappa}$ \\
            \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multirow{3}{*}{} & \multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}$p_0 (s) = p_0^* ,p_0^* \leq p_y$\\ $p_0 (s) = p_y + \frac{(\lambda^i-\kappa)(p_0^*-p_y)}{\lambda^i+\lambda^d (s) -\kappa},p_0^* > p_y$\end{tabular}} \\
            \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Loading–collapse curve\\ (LC)\end{tabular} &  &  \\
            &  &  \\
            \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Shear strength critical-\\ state parameter\end{tabular}} & $M(s) = M$ & M(s) = M_\text{dry} - (M_\text{dry}-M_\text{sat})\left( \frac{M_\text{sat}}{M_\text{dry}}\right)^{s/p_\text{atm}} \\ \cline{2-3} 
            \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{$p_s=k_ss$}} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Tensile strength\\ parameter\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{4}{*}{$\begin{array}{l}F= 3J_{2D} - \displaystyle \frac{M^2(s)}{9} (J_1 + 3{ k_s} s)\left[ 3p_0(s) - J_1\right] = 0 \\ G = 3J_{2D} - \displaystyle \frac{\alpha M^2(s)}{9} (J_1 + 3{ k_s} s)\left[ 3p_0(s) - J_1\right] = 0 \end{array}$}} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Yield surface\\ (triaxial)\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\
            \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Plastic potential \\ (triaxial)\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}%
    }
\end{table}
```

Comment: Welcome! Great you've posted code. Could you complete it so it can be compiled, please?

Answer (score 2):

In something like

```
Oldecop & Alonso
```

LaTeX will see that you want 2 columns, but you haven't specified 2 - only 1 here. You probably want

```
Oldecop \& Alonso
```

instead --- that is, you want to typeset an ampersand sign in the output.